# Cmd+Enter no longer opens search result in a background tab

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-search

I used to make a large amount of use of the `Cmd+Enter` (or `Ctrl+Enter` on Windows) shortcut in Google Search results in Chrome to open the result in a new tab without switching to that tab. Recently this has stopped working - `Enter` still works to open a link, and `Shift+Enter` still works to open in a new window, but the `Cmd+Enter` shortcut has stopped working. Could this be a setting in my account or is it just something taken away in a new Chrome release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Chromium ([#451060](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451060)).

> Merge of r189541 approved for m41 branch 2272.

So it should be fixed in the Chrome's 41 version.